# RabbitMQ: Control messages sent to subscribers

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using a subscription based consumer model for RabbitMQ. All messages are pushed to the same queue. The prefetch count is also set to 10 for all consumers. The messages in the queue are of different types.

I want a mechanism to tell RabbitMQ server to send only X number of messages of Type A and Y number of messages of Type B and Z number of messages of Type C to any consumer at any given instant.

I know that I can achieve this by having three different queues to hold different types of messages and have all consumers connect to the queues using different prefetch counts.

I am looking for a way to achieve the same using a single queue and provide some conditions that RabbitMQ server can check before sending messages to consumers.

Comment: And how exactly message type is defined? How rabbit will know which message is of which type?

Comment: I was thinking to use the BasicProperties "Type" field in the message meta-data or if there is any other header that I can use, I can change that as well

Comment: I don't really think it's possible. Besides other things - it's also against "queue" nature - you expect oldest message to be processed first but with your logic message can be skipped in favor of another message based on it's type. Plus as you know yourself - it could (and should) be implemented with multiple queues. Why you cannot use multiple queues?

Comment: I raised this when I saw priority queues being supported in RabbitMQ and header exchanges also. This felt like a combination of both, I could be wrong. I didn't want to use multiple queues because we already have some instance management and monitoring logic written based on the queue depth and rate, etc. I was looking for an option that will have minimal impact on what we already have.

Comment: you are right, rabbit started supporting priority queue, you can see more here https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html